# Return list of elements in group by query on Apache druid

Tags: group-by, druid

Having information stored as:

```
id;name;item;
1;one;1;
2;two;2;
1;one;3;
```

I want to group the items by id so I obtain:

```
id;items
1,[1,3]
2,[2]
```

Is there a way to achieve this on Apache Druid? I can only find examples of group by queries with sum, count, etc.

For example, in Oracle I would use JSON_ARRAYAGG or LISTAGG functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Druid with SQL queries or native queries?

Documentation for native queries:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/groupbyquery.html

Documentation for SQL queries:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html

I particularly use SQL because there is no noticeable difference in performance and SQL is mature knowledge. Newer versions of Druid provide graphical user interface for testing queries.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Druid has no solution to combine data which are not "grouped" by. The only solution is to do this in your application logic.